# passport.session() gives internal server error

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am facing this strange issue here. I am using Passport.js for authentication in my app (using Express.js and Passport.js). I am also storing sessions into a database. 
Now, whenever I try to use passport session (`app.use(passport.session())`) in my app it gives me `500 Internal server error`. I am not even able to load index page. But interestingly if I comment that line in my code everything works fine. Here is my code of passport configuration

```
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
    store: new pgSessionStore( {
        knex: require('knex')(require('./knexfile')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development']),
        tableName: 'sessions',
        createtable: false
    }),
    secret: 'secret',
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
//app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
```

Can anyone please point out what could be causing this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check on here, maybe you can try to replace some codes in `app.js` like on link below :
https://github.com/egin10/login-passport/blob/master/app.js
on line `39` to `48`

This is for define Passport Strategy : 
https://github.com/egin10/login-passport/blob/master/routes/users.js

I hope it help you.
maybe your proble on session, you can try to check some links above.